# What does Greek Christos mean

Tags: christmas, messiah

It is claimed that Greek Christos given to Jesus means anointed one and thus the same as Messiah. But I need to have proof and evidence that Greeks christened (anointed) kings or priests before Jesus came. After Greek Jews called Jesus the Christ, then afterward it is very easy to make claims that it means anointed or christened or chosen because that is what Greek Christians have done for 2000 years is christen its members instead of baptizing them. Christening them to all be kings with Jesus. However, where did pagan Greeks use their pagan word Christos to mean they anointed kings or priests. Are there any pre-Christian proofs. Otherwise I see Christos as clearly being the Greek return of Noah the Savior (Xisuthros) being Christos. I say this because Noah died on Greek December 25 and before three pagan Persian Magi priests claim on Dec 25 that it was about 50-day old Jesus (40 days on Kislev 25), they had already claimed that 1460 years of 365 leap days after Noah's death came returning and anointed Persian king Cyrus as Christ in 560bc to rule 30 years.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) (if you haven't already done so) and browse the [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) in order to see [how we are different from other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|1.9038).

Comment: See also, on hermeneutics.SE: [Was there any significance to the term χριστὸς in koine Greek outside of Judeo-Christian thought?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/10370/3555) I think that should pretty much answer the (part of this that is actually a) question.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on Hermeneutics.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but in regards to "I need proof",  I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  See: the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/).  Put simply, [we're not here to convince you.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/)

Comment: This really sounds more like a statement of personal opinion in the guise of a question.

Comment: "Christening" a child does not mean to anoint. It means to "make Christian", and infant baptized refer to it as "baptism " as often as they refer to it as "Christening ".

Answer (score 6):

[The Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) is a Greek translation of the (Hebrew) Old Testament and was completed by 132 BC. As the Old Testament contains many references to an "anointed one" (transliterated to English as "Messiah"), the decision by the (Jewish) translators to translate this word to the Greek "Christos" would have been driven by the need to find the nearest equivalent word in the Greek language to their own (Jewish) cultural concept.  Greek customs and practices are largely irrelevant, what matters is the Jewish cultural practices and concepts and whether the word they chose to refer to them was a valid translation choice.